# RST packet and server behavior

Tags: tcp, connection, client-server, rst

If a client send one RST packet to a server, how will the server react?

Client ----RST---->  Server

Does the server close the connexion immediatly or does it wait for another packet to be received?
A)
Client ----RST---->  Server
Client <---RST----  Server

B)
Client ----RST---->  Server
Client --PUSH+ACK-->  Server
Client <----RST----  Server

Does it behaves like A) or B)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a RST is sent from either the server or the client, the connection should be terminated immediately. That's not to say packets won't necessarily already be on the wire, or already in queue to be sent by the opposing side, but a RST is basically a forced and abrupt hang-up.

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol